# Secondary monitor not detected after Windows Update

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

Today I installed 24 "critical" updates for Windows 7. After rebooting, my secondary monitor is not detected. It is not showing up in the control panel screen resolutions settings dialog, or device manager. The NVidia Control Panel cannot find it with the "Rigorous display detection" button available from the "my display is not found link" in "Set up multiple displays".

I have powered down everything, unplugged the monitors and plugged them back in etc.

Here is the list of updates installed (nothing seems related to video):
[image]

Has anyone else had this problem? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try reinstalling the NVidia driver without the second monitor connected?

Restart, then try and connect it back up.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update to anyone still looking this up.  I was having the same problem with my GTX 470 and the newest (Sept 18 2011) drivers not showing on my LG 46 inch tv in the Nvidia control panel.  I am using a DVI-hdmi adapter connected to a 12 foot hdmi cable.  It is very hard to find mini-hdmi or long dvi cables in Alaska.

Anyhow, even though the TV was not showing up at all in the Nvidia panel, I did notice by accident that when I opened up My Documents the window did not appear on my computer monitor. I happened to look behind be and there it was, on my TV...even though Nvidia did not think it existed.  So i instead right clicked the desktop and went to screen resolution and sure enough windows recognized my TV and i was able to do what I wanted with it.

From reading online further, it seems there is a disconnect somewhere between Nvidia's drivers (and some day also ATI's) and Windows 7.  Not sure where the problem lies but this solution worked for me at least, though it is not ideal (i am sure people with 3d tv's need access to the nvidia panel for this)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  In my case, the duplicate display work, but not the extended display.

At soon i update the graphics driver for an older versions, both displays start to work and will work until I reboot.  After reboot, only one display is detected and I again need to update the
graphics driver for older or new version (no difference).

Both displays were working fine before the update.